# G++ new ABI problems

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

I got a problem with the new ABI introduced for C++11 in GCC. After upgrading to GCC 5.3 my project does no longer compile. The error messages I get are simple:

```
undefined reference to `tokenize(std::__cxx11::basic_string'  ...more characters
```

or

```
undefined reference to `extract(std::string const&)'
```

So, it looks like I messed something up and GCC is unable to decide whether I want the old ABI or the new one (the `__cxx11::` part is missing from some error messages, and present in others)?

I tried several solutions to resolve the issue:

- passing `-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0` to GCC,
- passing `-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1` to GCC,
- setting the macro directly in source code,
- setting the `abi_tag` attribute on the declarations GCC complained about when passed the `-Wabi-tag` flag,

Unfortunately, neither of them worked (i.e. allowed the code to compile). The one thing I know is that only functions returning `std::string` or taking it as a parameter fail to link. Which is to be expected, given what I read about the problem on the Internet. I was unable to reproduce the issue in a simple, example program to present it here.

Is there any obvious solution to my problem, that I am missing?

Comment: That's a linker error, not a compiler error. It suggests that the compiled objects and libraries you are trying to link were compiled with different ABIs.

Comment: @rici Yes, you're correct. I am aware that the problem occurs during linking. However, it is the compiler that emits the code to be linked (or is my understanding lacking?). What I don't know is why does G++ emit code sometimes using new, and sometimes old ABI even when I am doing full recompiles of the code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This error indicates that you're linking to some code or library that has not been recompiled by gcc 5.3, and was compiled by an earlier version of gcc, using the earlier version of the ABI.

If you are linking with some external libraries, besides the standard C++ library, those external libraries need to be recompiled (and reinstalled).

If you are not linking with any external libraries, and you are only linking together your own code, some of your source modules must not've been recompiled yet. Recompile everything. Make sure to wipe all existing object modules, with `make clean`, or the equivalent for whatever build system you're using.

Comment: I am linking only my own code. I also `make clean`'d and `make recompile`'d.Turns out I must have a bug in my Makefile. After I manually deleted all `.o` files I got a nice, clean, test-passing build. I am accepting your answer. Thanks!

Comment: I wonder what was your final solution. Did you have to add abi-tags manually to any classes or methods? I wonder if old code could just be compiled as before (breaking abi without generating any errors)

Comment: @Georg Sorry for a *very* late answer. I didn't have to do anything, just a full recompile. It turned out that I had a bug in my Makefile (written by hand) and it was deleting all `.o` files; so I had a mixture of files that had been compiled using old ABI and the new one. Turns out it was nothing arcane, really. The old code "could just be compiled as before" without breaking the ABI.