# GNU C++ ABI version checking

Tags: c++, g++, abi

GNU C++ (`g++`), and the associated linker, do not seem to perform an explicit version check for ABI differences with libraries being linked.  Instead, ABI incompatibility errors are simply reported as a list of "undefined reference" errors at link time.

Is there a technical reason that the linker can't, or shouldn't, perform an explicit ABI version compatibility check?

Example questions caused by ABI incompatibilities:

- [Undefined reference to google::protobuf::internal::empty_string_[abi:cxx11]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30124264/86967)
- [G++ new ABI problems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34970607)

Comment: Are you mainly asking about ABI incomptability caused by C++11 vs earlier versions, or about ABI incompatibility caused by libraries compiled with different compilers? In the latter case, I don't know if it's a technical, but there's a clear practical reason. In the former case, again I think different compilers handle it differently. Presumably, doing it this way means that "sometimes" you can get away with a questionable configuration where some things about CXX11 and some are not, but at the boundaries it's never an issue?

Comment: @ChrisBeck: I'm specifically thinking of a library that is compiled with a different version of the same compiler, and is as a result incompatible with the application being linked.